# Parse.com - PHP Add Query - ivalid type for key userid

Tags: php, curl, key, parse-platform

Hi I am trying to do a query to Parse.  com and I use right parameters, but I receive from JSON response this: `{"code":111,"error":"invalid type for key userid, expected *_User, but got string"}`

Here is the code:

```
 $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Tasks';   
 $headers = array(  
   "Content-Type: application/json",  
   "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,  
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey  
 );  
 $objectData = '{"userid":"hQsxiherY2", "tasktitle":"my first title", "taskcontent":"my first content"}';  
 $rest = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$objectData);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
 $response = curl_exec($rest);  
 echo $response;   
 curl_close($rest);
```

Something is wrong in $objectData->userid maybe I don't send something right... Anyone who use Parse. com and knows where is my mistake ? What I have to send ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `userid` column is actually a pointer, not a string column for the ID. That is the correct way to link objects.

When you query using a pointer you need to create a pointer properly.

Instead of a string ID `"hQsxiherY2"` you need to declare a pointer to the `_User` class:

```
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"hQsxiherY2"}
```

So in your code above your full `$objectData` would be:

```
$objectData = '{"userid":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"hQsxiherY2"}, "tasktitle":"my first title", "taskcontent":"my first content"}';
```